# SSRS - Display grouped detail columns in multiple rows in section

Tags: reporting-services

I have to prepare a report in SSRS and getting a result set of stocks group by on stock number. I have show some columns in one row but others beneath this row and 5 separated rows. Its a detail report should be displayed in section like below. All columns in dataset are in one row. I have tried many ways but cannot create such format. Please SSRS experts provide some suggestions.

```
Stock#   Description  Inventory  column4   column5  column6  column7
00001    Some stock   9034        122      xyz       123     ABC
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Product: Product1
Catalog: Catalog1
Buyer  : Buyer                 Vendor-1: Vendor1   Price:455    Date:mm/dd/yy
Alias : xyz
Notes: comments
Tendor#: 4334                  Vendor:Vendorx
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Totals: 89908.7998

00002    Some stock   8034        422      xyz       123     ABC
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Product: Product2
Catalog: Catalog2
Buyer  : Buyer2                 Vendor-2: Vendor2   Price:555    Date:mm/dd/yy
Alias : xyz
Notes: comments2
Tendor#: 5634                  Vendor:Vendorx
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Totals: 89908.7998
```

Comment: Please post your incoming dataset data for the report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. Use List control and found this at this link.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/microsoft_in_education/archive/2013/03/09/ssrs-using-a-list-item-to-display-details.aspx

Got what I was looking.